# How to fix routes in node js not working?

Tags: node.js

Anyone can help me I am new to node js and I am stuck with this error it return 404 not found when I am trying to visit http://localhost:5000/api/items on my postman..

this is the file items.js

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

```
//Items Model
const Item = require('../../models/Item');


router.get('/', (req, res) => {
Item.find()
.sort({date: -1})
.then(items => res.json(items))

});

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const newItem = new Item({
        name: req.body.name

    });
        newItem.save().then(item => res.json(item));
    
    });


module.exports = router;
```

this is the server.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

const items = require('./routes/api/items');

const db = require('./config/keys').mongoURI;
mongoose.connect(db, {useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true })
.then(() => console.log('connected to mongo'))
.catch(err => console.log(err));

app.use('api/items', items);

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`port started ${port}`));
```

Comment: Show a whole js-file with routes

Comment: RIghtly said @Anatoly. It's always best to share your snippet of code rather than the image so that it's easy for others to understand and give you the optimum solution.

Comment: Please show server.js file also for the reference

Comment: Check my answer you just need to change your router.get('URL') in order to work and make sure you enter the same in postman too

Comment: @JatinMehrotra I already change my postman to localhost:5000/ but getting the same answer sir..

Comment: please show your server.js code

Comment: @PritthishNath I already added it sir..

Answer (score 1):

add a '/' before pathname in server.js

```
app.use('/api/items', items);
```

localhost:5000/api/items should work then

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the following changes to your server.js

1. **import your router module**

   ```
    const express = require('express');

    const mongoose = require('mongoose');

    const router = require('path of the router module');

    const app = express();

    app.use(express.json());

    app.use(router); //to use your router


    const items = require('./routes/api/items');

    const db = require('./config/keys').mongoURI;
    mongoose.connect(db, {useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true })
    .then(() => console.log('connected to mongo'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

    app.use('/api/items', items);

    const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

    app.listen(port, () => console.log(`port started ${port}`));
   ```

Try this:-

As I can see in the image of "vscode"

you have used `router.get("/")`

whereas in postman you are using URL for GET request as  `localhost:5000/api/items`.

Either change your backend code to `router.get("/api/items")` or correct your postman request to `localhost:5000/`

Comment: i already change it to localhost:5000/ but getting same error

Comment: hi sir thanks for your reply I already edited it above